# Going from an std::thread to the related pthread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

In Linux, I need to check if an address belongs to the stack of the thread or not. I have found that `pthread_attr_getstack` works for the purpose.

I presume that std::thread is based on pthreads, and so from my std::thread I may find a pthread and use it along with `pthread_attr_getstack` in order to check if the pointer points inside the stack. Is that possible? How?

Comment: `std::thread` can have a member function named `native_handle()`; it's implementation-defined whether it exists. If it exists, it returns an object of type `native_handle_type` whose meaning and possible uses are implementation defined. If that's useful to you, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

> std::thread::native_handle: Returns the implementation defined
> underlying thread handle.

See more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle

Having obtained `native_handle` (and reasonably believing your implementation is based on pthreads, as it might not be!) you can pass this handle to any `pthread` routines your heart desires.

Comment: I didn't, but as you state it I cannot know if the implementation is done via a p_thread or in what way. So also with what you tell me I cannot know that this is the right handle.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, well, once you go into such depth, you simply need to know your implementation.

Comment: By the way the compiler used is gcc from what said I suppose pthread is the implementation :-) .

Comment: Well, you can trivially check by comparing `pthread_self()` with that native handle. I haven't tried this, so do let us know how you get on.

Comment: @Useless, which, of course, is no formal gurantee :)

Comment: Um, that cppreference documentation isn't quite right. Whether `native_handle()` **exists** is implementation defined. **If** it exists it returns an object of type `native_handle_type`, whose **meaning and uses** are implementation defined. So, yes, it **might** be useful here, but you have to read the compiler's documentation. Even if you know that your implementation is based on pthreads, you still have to check the documentation to determine what that `native_handle_type` actually is and what it can actually be used for.

Comment: I finally checked it ! Compiling via g++ and using pthread_self() and native_handle() give the same address. So it is safe to deduce that in gcc std::thread is implemented on top of pthreads and everything more elaborated than what directly allowed by the standard may be done using native_handle().